# Input in the same line of the message (terminal)

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

Is there an Syntax that allows me to read the input from the user in the same line of the `System.out.println() line`?

Example:

```
What is your name?:(<-- Output)    Jack (<-- Input from user in the same line)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `println`

Then your next input will be on the same line.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you.

```
System.out.print("What is your name?");
```